# Unable to animate div element using CSS when assigned to multiple classes

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply a CSS animation to multiple div elements as in the following HTML code:

```
{% for i in player_range %}
<div id="container-frame-{{ i }}" class="container-frame borderblinker">
...
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Where container-frame is the frame of the div element and borderblinker is the css needed to perform animation for these borders.

Below is the CSS style I'm applying for each element.

```
.container-frame {
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: whitesmoke;
        }
@keyframes borderblinker {
    0%    {border-color: #444444;}
    10%    {border-color: #4C4C4C;}
    20.0%  {border-color: #4C3333;}
    30.0%  {border-color: #660000;}
    40.0%  {border-color: #4C1919;}
    50.0%  {border-color: #990000;}
    60.0%  {border-color: #CC0000;}
    70.0%  {border-color: #FF0000;}
    100.0%  {border-color: #FF0000;}
    }
div{
    animation-name: borderblinker;
    animation-timing-function: step-end ;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite ;
    animation-direction: alternate ;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    }
```

The border style is applied correctly, however, the div elements do not blink. Any idea what could be the problem ?

Comment: You're missing a quote in the HTML. Try `<div id="container-frame-{{ i }}" class="container-frame borderblinker">`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It was a typo in my question, I had this quote already in my code :)

Comment: Bummer . . . that would have been an easy fix :) Have done "inspect element (F12)" yet?

Comment: Yes I tried. However, since my software is running on a tablet I can't have full control of how the HTML is handled. Here is a screen shot it shows that the different divs are getting the class assignment properly http://imgh.us/Screenshot_from_2017-03-01_15-24-09.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you forgot to set an "animation-duration".**

But there is also some unclear code:

The problem is the class "container-frame". 
Because your div is not only a div but also has the class "container-frame", it gets a fixed border-style and border-color. Even though you have defined an animation for the tag "div" below, the class selector gets the priority because of the cascading order. classes get prioritised over tag selectors.

http://monc.se/kitchen/38/cascading-order-and-inheritance-in-css

You could solve the problem by targeting the animation div also with a class selector instead of just the tag selector:

```
div.container-frame{
    animation-name: borderblinker;
    animation-timing-function: step-end ;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite ;
    animation-direction: alternate ;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I try to add "div" before .container-frame the IDE tells me that this selector is never used. :( and nothing changes.

Comment: I added animation duration as well

Comment: if you have a space between "div" and the class selector, remove it. Your selector should look like this: "div.container-frame" and then it should work. Im sorry that was a mistake on my code.     https://jsfiddle.net/y0ty7t80/5/

Comment: Thanks I figured out what the problem was. It was that the border-color was having a higher priority. Now it works!

Answer (score 1):

When I deleted the border-color from container-frame, the problem was solved. Thanks to @KevDev

```
@keyframes example {
        0%    {border-color: #444444;}
        10%    {border-color: #4C4C4C;}
        20.0%  {border-color: #4C3333;}
        30.0%  {border-color: #660000;}
        40.0%  {border-color: #4C1919;}
        50.0%  {border-color: #990000;}
        60.0%  {border-color: #CC0000;}
        70.0%  {border-color: #FF0000;}
        100.0%  {border-color: #FF0000;}
    }
    .container-frame {
        position: absolute;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 5px;
        animation-duration: 0.5s;
        animation-name: example;
        animation-timing-function: step-end ;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite ;
        animation-direction: alternate ;
    }
```